# Компиляция сборки проекта

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

Подскажите люди добрые, как убрать .pdb .tlog .obj .recipe .log файлы из папки Debug/Release при сборке проекта, чтобы после сборки был только исполняемый файл. Я уже многоe облазил, но дельного ничего не нашёл (VS русская)

Comment: Ну .pdb файл там нужен, так как это отладочные символы. А остальные помещаются в промежуточную папку (Intermediate directory).